# bulma have 2 rows with 2 columns on desktop but have 4 rows with 1 column

Tags: bulma

Is there an more elegant way to achieve this using bulma:

Desktop (https://jsfiddle.net/AlexZeitler/2odamk03/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
      <span>adress</span>
    </div>
   <div class="column">
      <span>city</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
      <span>phone</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <span>email</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tablet should look like this (https://jsfiddle.net/AlexZeitler/yuhxr13b/):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
      <span>adress</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
      <span>city</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
      <span>phone</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
      <span>email</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`.container` has a fixed `width` dependending on tablet or desktop mode:

```
.container {
  padding: 2em;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [tiles](https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/tiles/) when I do something similar.
Not shorter, but you don't have to worry about `.columns`

https://jsfiddle.net/0c38ejqa/

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the horizontal size of the colum divs using modifiers. There are many ways to do so. Here is one:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns is-tablet">
    <div class="column is-half">
      <span>adress</span>
    </div>
   <div class="column is-half">
      <span>city</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columns is-tablet">
    <div class="column is-half">
      <span>phone</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-half">
      <span>email</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```